# Length mismatch error when assigning new column labels in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The tab file I'm working with is missing the final column name.  When I attempt to repair the header by appending the missing value, I get a mismatch error.  Here's an example to illustrate the problem:

**toy example**

There should be a '' as the last element of the first list:

```
missingcol = [[gene, cell_1, '', cell_2]
               [MYC, 5.0, P, 4.0, A]
               [AKT, 3.0, A, 1.0, P]]
```

To fix this, I read the first line, appended a `''`, loaded `missingcol` into a pandas dataframe with `header=None` and skipping the first row, and redefined the column names with the modified header, like so:

```
fullheader = missingcol[0].append('')
fullheader = missingcol[0]

missingcol_dropheader = missingcol[1:]

df = pd.DataFrame(missingcol_dropheader, columns=fullheader)
df
```

Which gives me the error:

```
AssertionError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns
```

Last I checked, the new `fullheader` does, in fact, have 5 elements to match the five elements in the data frame.  *What is causing this continued mismatch and how do I fix it?*

**real example**

I get a similar error when I repeat these same steps, but when using `read_csv` method with my actual test case.  I ignore the header at line 0, and the three blank lines from lines 1-3, and drop an unwanted first column, but otherwise it's similar:

```
with open('CCLE_Expression_Entrez_2012-10-18.res', 'r') as f:
    header = f.readline().strip().split('\t')
header.append('') # missing empty colname over last A/P col

rnadf = pd.read_csv('CCLE_Expression_Entrez_2012-10-18.res', delimiter='\t', index_col=0, header=None, skiprows=[0,1,2,3])  
rnadf.columns = header
rnadf.drop([], axis=1, inplace=True)
rnadf.columns = header

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2073 elements, new values have 2074 elements
```

Very similar error to test case.  *What makes this error different to the test case and how do I fix it?*

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Please provide a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was the argument `index_col=0` was beginning column indexing at the gene names:

[image]

The above dataframe ended at 2073, which with 1-based indexing with the above argument, was 2073 elements: one element fewer than my repaired header.  This generated the following error:

`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2073 elements, new values have 2074 elements`

While the same `read_csv` command with `index_col=None` assigned a separate numerical index, putting the (in this case gene names) back into the dataframe from being just labels:

[image]

The above dataframe ended at the column number 2073, which is 2074 elements with zero-based indexing: the same length as my repaired header!  Problem solved:

[image]

Comment: Dead image links. Please do not put images :(

Comment: They're not dead, I see them just fine.